# Sonar coverage is showing zero percentage even though jest coverage is showing correctly

Tags: angular, jestjs, sonarqube

I am using jest for unit testing, jest is showing code coverage as expected but while I run the sonar the coverage is showing zero only.
package.json is like this below.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "sonar56x": true,
    "reportPath": "coverage",
    "reportFile": "test-report.xml",
    "indent": 4
  }
```

sonar-project.properties is like below.

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/test-report.xml
sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths=coverage/test-report.xml
```

remaining config is available jest.config.js.

why the coverage is not exposing to sonar?

Comment: updated the typo.

Comment: Can you add sonar logs?

Comment: Issue is resolved after deleting multiple report paths and kept the one below in properties file. 
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-report.xml